# help with sed matching optional newline

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this sed pattern to match a line and place content below the matched line. This is what I have working so far:

Content:

```
<element
    :sample1="foo"
    :sample-attr="$t('foo.bar')"
>
```

Working command:

```
sed  '/:sample-attr=.*/a :new-attr="true"' file.vue
```

This works and produces:

```
<element
        :sample1="foo"
        :sample-attr="$t('foo.bar')"
    :new-attr="true"
    >
```

But some files have attributes with multiline. Like:

```
:sample-attr="
    $t('foo.bar')
"
```

I need help with adjusting the sed pattern to match an optional newline. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to parse XML/HTML with sed ?

Comment: What is the name of the structured document format that this input data is written in? It almost looks like XML, apart from the colons.  This would be trivial to fix with e.g. `xmlstarlet`, had the input been ordinary XML (without the colons): `xmlstarlet edit --update '//element/@sample-attr' --value true --rename '//element/@sample-attr' --value 'new-attr' file.xml`

Comment: @GillesQuenot, yes XML semantics. But the entire content of the file is not XML

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for this tool. But the entire content of the file is not XML/HTML structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in both cases:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/(\s*):sample-attr="[^"]+"/$&$1:new-attr="true"/' file
<element
    :sample1="foo"
    :sample-attr="$t('foo.bar')"
    :new-attr="true"
>
```

You can use `perl -i -pe` to replace *in-line* (on-the-fly)

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you! I will have to start looking into Perl